# Como concatenar todos los elementos de un arreglo en una sola variable? C

Tags: array, c

Tengo un programa que convierte de ASCII a decimal. Los caracteres a convertir se almacenan en un arreglo tipo `char`. Al momento de la conversión, en la impresión de pantalla ya se muestran los caracteres convertidos a decimal (igual por posición) por ejemplo:

[0]= 'A' = 65
[1]= 'B' = 66
[2]= 'C' = 67

Ahora lo que necesito es concatenar todos los valores finales de ese arreglo dentro de una misma variable de tipo entero para posteriormente convertirla a binario, es decir:

```
variable=656667;
```

Comment: ¿Qué has hecho hasta ahora? ¿Dónde te has bloqueado?

Comment: ¿Cuántos elementos tiene tu array? Un entero está limitado a 32 bits (o 64 si es de tipo `long long`), por lo que tu array también debería estar limitado a 4 entradas (u 8 respectivamente). Por otro lado, esta pregunta tiene pinta de ser un [XY problem](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy) ¿Para qué necesitas esto exactamente?

Comment: ¿No te sirve `variable = [0] * 10000 + [1] * 100 + [2]`?

Comment: Hasta el momento ya convierte en ASCII, solo me falta concatenar todos esos resultados por posición para unirlos en una variable de tipo entero. Mi array tiene 5 elementos únicamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando la sugerencia de PaperBirdMaster, y asumiendo que el arreglo presenta un tamaño fijo de valores, la respuesta mas sencilla es la siguiente:

```
long long int variable = 0;
variable = arreglo[0] * 100000000 + arreglo[1] * 1000000 + arreglo[2] * 10000 + arreglo[3] * 100 + arreglo[4];
```

Aquí tomamos en cuenta también lo descrito por abulafia, en donde el tamaño del tipo `long long` será suficiente para almacenar los 5 bytes que necesitas en tu ejercicio.

Recordemos que el estándar para el caso de `long long int` no indica algún tamaño en específico, sino que lo deja a la implementación. Tomado de ISO/IEC 9899:2018, esto es lo que indica:

> The rank of `long long int` shall be greated than the rank of `long
>   int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `int`, which shall be
>   greated than the rank of `short int`, which shall be greater than the
>   rank of `signed char`

En cuanto a la operación de multiplicación, lo que esto hará será multiplicar el valor en el arreglo por el valor de su posición y agregarlo (sumarlo) a `variable` el cual es nuestro acumulador.